# 3SPI, 1 I2C, 1 UART connections to esp32

Tags: spi, esp32

I am trying to make a number of digital connections to an esp32 [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/891/esp32_wroom_32e_esp32_wroom_32ue_datasheet_en-1855879.pdf)
As shown in the photo below.  I am having difficulty finding a way to read 3 ICs with SPI outputs, because I only have 2 free SPI busses on the ESP. One is used by flash.  Each SPI connection is coming from an Pt-100 RTD which I usually use the chip Max31865 to take the sensors reading to SPI [datasheet](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/MAX31865AAP+T.pdf).  So my questions are:

1. Can I safely make a 3rd SPI connection with the ESP?
2. Is there a way to take a Pt100's reading to analog with preferably
   16bit resolution?  Cannot be a breakout board.
3. Is there an IC that can take multiple Pt100 inputs and combine them into 1 SPI connection?

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put several MAX31865 devices on the same SPI bus. They will share the clock and data lines, but each one must have its own separate chip select \$\overline{CS}\$ signal. So, you just need one SPI interface and a separate GPIO output pin for each device.

As an aside, be careful not to confuse **resolution** with **accuracy**. The accuracy of the MAX31865 appears to be about 10 times worse than its resolution. Using a converter with 16-bit resolution might not give you any better accuracy.

Comment: If I choose to use the VSPI bus and select CS1->IO5, CS2->IO34, CS3->IO35.  Where IO34&35 are just regular GPIOs will this work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the details of the ESP32 SPI interfaces.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is for a normal MCU I can select any GPIO for CS?

Comment: @Feynman137 Yes, CS is a simple high/1 or low/0 signal. However, which of those are On and Off is different per IC.